# Do mobile browsers currently use srcset to conserve bandwidth?

Tags: html, mobile, bandwidth, responsive-images, srcset

We know that the `img` tag's [`srcset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/srcset) property is important in creating responsive websites.

Do mobile browsers on cellular data currently use `srcset` to optimize for bandwidth? For example, if a user has a high-pixel-density iPhone in [low data mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210596), might Safari choose to download a lower-resolution image offered by `srcset` compared to what it might download if on Wifi?

I'm happy to find out it's not currently supported by any browser, or it's partially supported, or it might someday be supported, or it'll never be supported because there's something wrong with my mental model.

(For a project I have some bandwidth-constrained users and I'd like to know whether to just offer a "Click here for a high-resolution render" link or if I can assume `srcset` will take care of bandwidth-conservation for me.)